# Barcode Scanning AutoTrigger on LiveChange event

Tags: sapui5

I have a barcode scanning functionality for my SAPUI5 application. First the user will see a pop-up where he can do barcode scanning and if the scanned barcode is correct it will trigger the Next button and will in turn display another pop-up for the next barcode scanning. For the first barcode, the user must scan 6-7 digits while on the second barcode, it should be 5. My problem is with the autotrigger for the fist barcode. When user scans for 7 digits, it triggers the Next 2x. Is there a way to know the last length of the scanned barcode text?

Here is my liveChange event for TextInput

```
                        liveChange: function(oEvent) {

                        sText = oEvent.getParameter('value');
                        parent1 = oEvent.getSource().getParent();

                            if ((typeof sText != 'undefined') && (sText.length >= 6) )
                            {

                                sap.ui.getCore().byId(t.createId("costCenterInput")).setValue(sText);
                                setTimeout(function() { 
                                    console.log(parent1.getBeginButton());
                                    if (parent1.getBeginButton() != null){
                                    parent1.getBeginButton().firePress(oEvent); 
                                    }

                                    }, 5000);

                            }
                    }
```

The problem with this code is that an external barcode scanner acts as a Bluetooth keyboard that inputs the data one at a time. So say we scan 1234567, upon entering 6 it will already trigger even with the timeout and will trigger again when entering 7.

new code

```
    onScanAddressMobile: function(){

    var t = this;
    t.oBundle = this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle();
    var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog(t.createId("ccDialog"), {
            title: t.oBundle.getText("COST_CENTER"),
            type: 'Message',
            content: [
                new sap.m.Text({ text: t.oBundle.getText("SCAN_COST_CENTER")}),
                new sap.m.Input(t.createId("costCenterInput"), {
                    type: "Number",
                    liveChange: 

                    function(oEvent){
                        t.onLiveChange(oEvent);
                    }

                }),
      .....some more code here...
      },

      onLiveChange : function(event) {
        //alert("onLiveChange");
                    var value = event.getParameter("value");
                    if (value && value.length === 6) {
                        alert("6 character");
                        this.timer = setTimeout(this.gotoNextPage(value), 4000);  
                    } else if (value && value.length > 6) {
                        alert("6 or more");
                        if (this.timer) {
                          clearTimeout(this.timer);
                        }
                        this.gotoNextPage(value);
                    }
    },
```

Comment: Please note that it's considered a bad practice to call a control's event handler (`.byId("control").fireEvent()`). It is better to isolate the logic from the button's handler into a separate method, and call this from both the button's handler as well as the liveChange handler. With this, you would have better separation of concerns.

Comment: Hi. Can you please show me a sample code for this one? Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, sample code here: http://jsbin.com/kolacez/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for this this is useful but I'm still having problems with the liveChange event. I have a dialog with a liveChange event. I copied what you did on your jsbin. When I entered a 7 character, on the 6th character, it is going to the condition for the 6 character logic but it should go to the else condition. I hope you can point out where I did wrong. See above post for the updated code.

Comment: That's how it's intended. When you enter the 6th character it will set a timer and will launch gotoNextPage when the next character isn't received in time. When you enter the 7th character, the timer set when the 6th character was entered is cancelled and the gotoNextPage is immediately launched. I'll also adjust the answer a bit to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A barcode scanner that works as a bluetooth keyboard will "key" in its data quite rapidly. If you have received 6 digits and then didn't receive anything for perhaps 250ms, you can consider the barcode complete and skip to the next page.

If you have received 7 digits, you don't even need to wait anymore, but can immediately skip to the next page.

So I guess your code would have to look something like this:

```
onLiveChange : function(event) {
    var value = event.getParameter("value");
    if (value && value.length === 6) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.gotoNextPage, 250)  
    } else if (value && value.length > 6) {
        if (this.timer) {
          clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }
        this.gotoNextPage();
    }
}
```

Please find an example with slightly longer time-out in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/kolacez/1/edit?html,output

This is what will happen:

- Char 1: Nothing
- Char 2: Nothing
- Char 3: Nothing
- Char 4: Nothing
- Char 5: Nothing
- Char 6: A timer is set, if character 7 isn't received within a certain timeframe, the barcode is assumed to be complete and it will launch gotoNextPage.
- Char 7: The timer is cancelled and gotoNextPage is started directly.

So in case a 7 chars barcode is received, the logic for both char 6 and char 7 is executed, but because the timer-action of char 6 is cancelled, the gotoNextPage method is launched only once.

Comment: Weird...mine is still calling the goToNextPage on the 6th char. I even set my timer to 10 secs...so it's still calling the goToNextPage twice :(

Comment: I actually tried editting your jsbin. I just added value as a parameter to this.gotoNextPage(value). It's already calling at 6th character.

Comment: Can you send me the url to your jsbin?

Comment: I'm afraid that your changes have broken the code. In the setTimeout method, you can only reference the function you want to call. In your code, you're actually calling it (the diffference is in the parantheses behind the method name), i.e. gotoNextPage() instead of gotoNextPage. If you want to add your own parameters, you will have to create an anonymous function and call the gotoNextPage from there. Example here: http://jsbin.com/jaripo/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3):

Usually, barcode-scanners can be configured to send a 'return' value at the end of the scanned characters (or any other character, but the Chr(13) is most common as it could instantly submit a form when schanned into an input field

See if you can configure yours, and simply check for the last character (return)

Comment: Assuming that I get to configure the return value of the barcode scanner...how should I get that value from my code? Can the return value be seen on an input field (if I'm putting the scanned value on one).

Comment: Simply add a `change` event handler to your `<Input>` control, and in the handler `oEvent.getSource().getValue()` will contain the scanned value

Comment: Good one Robin (upvoted :). In that case you could leverage the change instead of liveChange event.

Comment: Not only that, but you don't need to count/rely on the number of characters returned as well. And as far as I know, most -- if not all -- scanners allow you to add a prefix and/or suffix to the scanned code (a prefix might be handy to determine start of scanning, and suffix to handle the scanned content (in this case, `key === 13`)